# How can I create new columns, based on the numeric value of another column

Tags: r, loops, indexing, columnsorting

I have a df (`chpt4`) with 1000+ participants, and the dates when tests where taken. I would like to accomodate the dates according to how many months have passed between the follow up (`t1:t4`) and the baseline (`t0`). For this purpose I created 4 additional columns (`difft0t2:difft0t4`) that show exaclty the months elapsed between the tests. The image is what I have now.

[image: this is what i have]

I am grouping the months in 5 different categories: (also I thought this vectors would help me as a counter)

```
FU6 <- 1:9
FU12 <- 10:18 
FU24 <- 19:30
FU36 <- 31:42
FU48 <- 43:54
```

My original idea was to start indexing the values of the `difft0t1` column, that belong to the above ranges using `which()`

```
which(chpt4$difft0t1 %in% c(FU6)) #this works

which(chpt4$difft0t1 %in% c(FU14)) #this doesn't work at all
```

**...and use that outcome number, as an index of which element to paste into another column.** Its just not working.

keeping with the image example from lines 243 and 244, I would like to outcome columns to look like this:

| baseline | FU6 | FU12 | FU24 | FU36 | FU48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-02-24 | NA | 2013-09-06 | 2014-02-21 | 2015-06-23 | NA |
| 2012-05-24 | NA | 2013-05-16 | NA | 2015-04-20 | 2016-05-12 |

Comment: I am not clear of the question, specifically how the `FU` integer sequences relate to desired `FU` dates and how your `which` code relates to desired `FU` dates. Consider re-drafting post for clarity. And `FU14` is not defined in post. Finally, please `dput` sample of data and not use images. See [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: So what if there are two or more tests in one same `FU` group? e.g. say if T1 and T2 are in FU24 (19 to 30 months away from T0) for any id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this

```
library (tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = "Test", values_to = "Dates") %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(new_col = as.numeric(round((Dates - first(Dates))/30,0))) %>%
  mutate(new_col = case_when(new_col == 0 ~ "Baseline",
                              new_col %in% 1:9 ~ "FU6",
                              new_col %in% 10:18 ~ "FU12",
                              new_col %in% 19:30 ~ "FU24",
                              new_col %in% 31:42 ~ "FU36",
                              new_col %in% 43:54 ~ "FU48")) %>% filter(!is.na(new_col)) %>%
  select(-Test) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = "id", names_from = "new_col", values_from = "Dates", values_fn = min)
  
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   id [4]
  id     Baseline   FU12       FU24       FU36       FU48      
  <chr>  <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1 waa000 2012-10-04 2013-09-05 NA         NA         NA        
2 waf84  2012-02-24 NA         2013-09-06 2015-06-23 NA        
3 waq593 2012-05-24 2013-05-16 NA         2015-04-20 2016-05-12
4 wcu776 2013-01-24 2014-01-23 NA         NA         NA
```

**NOTE** whenever there will be two dates in one group, minimum/first of those will be displayed.  `FU6` category will automatically in picture once the appropriate data is used.
sample data used

```
dput(df)

> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c("waa000", "waf84", "waq593", "wcu776"), 
    t0 = structure(c(15617, 15394, 15484, 15729), class = "Date"), 
    t1 = structure(c(15953, 15954, 15841, 16093), class = "Date"), 
    t2 = structure(c(NA, 16122, 16545, NA), class = "Date"), 
    t3 = structure(c(NA, 16609, 16933, NA), class = "Date"), 
    t4 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

> df
      id         t0         t1         t2         t3   t4
1 waa000 2012-10-04 2013-09-05       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
2  waf84 2012-02-24 2013-09-06 2014-02-21 2015-06-23 <NA>
3 waq593 2012-05-24 2013-05-16 2015-04-20 2016-05-12 <NA>
4 wcu776 2013-01-24 2014-01-23       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: hi @anilgoyal , this was a really good answer. I posted a kinda similar question yesterday, and I thought you might have an answer to it :) 
I hope you see this message before its deleted

Comment: Ok. Let me see and figure out something